# Setting a new project root in React Native

Tags: react-native

I created a React Native app using the create-native-app command but then decided to move the app to new directory location.
Attempting to run it now causes it to fail as it's looking for the package.json in the old location.
I've tried to reset the PROJECT_ROOT variable with variations of the SET command but I haven't got it right yet.

So, can someone please provide the correct SET command (or other command if it isn't the PROJECT_ROOT I need to change).
Alternatively, where is PROJECT_ROOT stored? I haven't found where it is in the project yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a absolutely new project at the location you want and then you copy the source code in the old project into the new one. That's all and you can start your work! :)) Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I went with in the end. But now I'm just curious - the project root must be stored somewhere. I want to know!